# Umbraco returning non-existing values

Tags: sql, view, umbraco, admin

A client asked us to move their Umbraco website. We moved it to a test environment first and everything went fine. When we moved it to the staging environment, weird stuff happened.

In the Umbraco Admin area, we've got some entries with fields. These fields are empty for X number of entries. However, in the view portion of the page (for the visitors), values are printed out for each entry! The values that are printed out are the values from the production environment. However, no connection strings in the web.config point to the production environment.

When we change the value in one of the entries, the view understands it and displays the correct one - but only on that single entry! The other ones still show the values from the production environment.

We've tried uploading the site, again and again, restarted app pools, cleared client cache, different browsers.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are these items on a search results page?  If so you may have to rebuild the Examine search index.

Comment: Yeah, rebuild indexes and maybe even try renaming App_Data/umbraco.config so it can be rebuilt from scratch?

Comment: The client had newer version of umbraco.config on the test/production server than on the stage server.. so the values didn't match the database, which caused the mixup. Embarassing :) First time deploying Umbraco, interesting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you've figured it out, but for anyone else who finds this, when deploying an Umbraco site, as a general rule you should NOT deploy the following:

- /App_Data/umbraco.config
- /App_Data/TEMP/ (the whole folder)
- /App_Data/cache/
- /App_Data/logs/

If you do deploy some of those files, you may get odd errors with content being wrong/out of date etc.